# Knowledge Article NormalizedScore - what is it?

Tags: apex, knowledge

I'm developing a Lightning Component to display Knowledge Articles alongside their overall rating. The [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_knowledgearticlevotestat.htm?search_text=knowledge) for `NormalizedScore` on the `KnowledgeArticleVoteStat` object says that this is the overall rating from 1 to 5, however upon testing I have an article that has a rating of 6.59!

How should we interpret this score? What is the best way to display the overall rating that takes into account either Thumbs Up/Down voting or star voting?

Comment: If it's outside the 1-5 area, might be a bug? Normalised score is based on number of thumbs up/down, and when those votes were cast (older votes have less effect).

Comment: I have raised a case, so we'll find out what Salesforce say about this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Confirmed to be a bug by Salesforce support. Possibly due to my org being a Trailhead Playground. They were certain this would not be an issue in production orgs.